display capture then to rtp but framerate won't catch up to what it needs to be
i'm trying to capture PC's current display (of playing game or so) then send that over to network via rtp (multicast stream). in rawvideo, yuv422p10 and in 59.94 framerate.
"
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60000/1001 -i desktop ^
-c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10 -b:v 5M ^
-f rtp -r 60000/1001 -sdp_file stream.sdp rtp://224.1.1.1:5004 " this is current command line
i'm using. but no matter what i do.. framerate won't go up to 59.94... it only go up to 37~39.is it too big for ffmpeg to handle? or am i doing something wrong?

-c:v rawvideo means that the video is not encoded, and uncompressed. Assuming the resolution is 1920x1080, the uncompressed video bandwidth is about 2.5Gbps (2.5 Gigabit per second) . Selecting -b:v 5M has no effect with rawvideo. Try recording 1 second to file: ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -framerate 60000/1001 -i desktop -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv422p10 -b:v 5M -t 1 tmp.yuv. The file size is about 500 MBytes... I suggest you to do some research about video encoding.

command line is just simply what chatgpt just told me to use. even without  b:v 5m, it won't work. like.. i don't want encoding, i need to send rawvideo to ethernet. (Trying capture display then send to st2110 [ip broadcasting standard] signal. if i change to 420p, it does go up to 60fps but 422p10 won't go up to 60fps.. beside encoding part, do ffmpeg avail to send that much big rawvideo data ?

I don't think this is an FFmpeg limitation. It is more likely related to the Ethernet bandwidth (speed). What is the resolution of the captured desktop? What is the Ethernet speed? Try sending to localhost IP 127.0.0.1 for checking if it's the Ethernet limitation.

Alright, will try tmrw once i go to work. The ethernet, im using 10g intel NIC. I need to send in 1920x1080, 59.94p. I will try to send to local if its ffmpeg or my command (or perhaps some other setting) issue. Thank you

Just tested with local port (127.0.0.1). FPS did got better though it doesn't meet my need. FPS does go up to 53-54 with 422p10 format and it hits my need (59.94) with 420p. I would still be somewhat happy enough to reach 53-54 to my nic though.

It's strange that it's just 53fps and not 59.94. I don't know if it's going to work, but you may try lossless codec like FFV1. Maybe also with NUT container. (Decode the video at the receiver side).
